# Stable Matching Problem

Tags: algorithms

Given 4 men and 4 women, each with his/her preference list, how can I have more than 2 stable matching? can anyone give me an example? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number the participants from 0 to 7 with men at even numbers and women at odd numbers. Everyone's preference list is

- (own number + 1) mod 8
- (own number + 3) mod 8
- (own number + 5) mod 8
- (own number + 7) mod 8

There are (at least) four stable matchings, such as the one where every man gets his third preference.